# How to set path to kubectl when installed using gcloud components install?

Tags: shell, gcloud, kubectl

Ok, I installed kubectl in the following way on my Mac:
1) installed gcloud using homebrew
2) installed kubectl using gcloud components install.

I want to run a shell script that calls kubectl directly. However, I get an error.
$ kubectl version
-bash: kubectl: command not found

I expected gcloud components install to set path variables so that I can call kubectl. Looks like that has not happened. I searched for kubectl in my mac but was not able to find it.

How can I get kubectl to work from command line?

Comment: Just to doublecheck: Did you execute `gcloud components install kubectl` as the [documentation states](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart) (the last parameter is missing in your question)? Alternatively it may work installing the kubernetes cli yourself: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-with-homebrew-on-macos ?

Comment: Yes, I executed gcloud components install kubectl . I was hoping to not have several instances of kubectl on my machine.

Answer (score 17):

**Short answer:**

On macOS, you may need to add a symlink: `sudo ln /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

**Long answer:**

I believe this is caused by installing kubectl via homebrew, then via gcloud, and then uninstalling the homebrew managed tool. homebrew will remove its symlink but gcloud doesn't add it back even when you reinstall kubectl.

To see if this is affecting you on macOS:

- See if gcloud has installed kubectl: `gcloud info | grep -i kubectl`

  - If you are having the problem I am, I'd expect to see the output look something like this:

    ```
      kubectl: [2019.05.31]
    Kubectl on PATH: [False]
    ```
  - When working you should see something like this:

    ```
      kubectl: [2019.05.31]
    Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]
      /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    ```
- Check for the symlink: `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep -i google-cloud-sdk`. That will show your links to google cloud binaries.

  - If `kubectl` isn't on the list then run `sudo ln /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for the explanation on the "long answer" part!

Answer (score 1):

The `gcloud info` command will tell you if and where kubectl is installed.

Per https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/, you can install `kubectl` with `brew install kubernetes-cli`. Alternatively, you can install the Google Cloud SDK per https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos, and then install `kubectl` with `gcloud components install kubectl`.

Comment: I did the second - installed using [gcloud components install kubectl]. After this step, I am wondering how to get calls to kubectl work since bash informs me that command is not found.

Comment: Can you share the output of `gcoud info` (with any sensitive data removed)?

Comment: I decided to `brew install kubernetes-cli`. However, I did run `gcloud info` that returns `Installation Root: [/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  kubectl: []
  gsutil: [4.33]
  bq: [2.0.34]
  core: [2018.07.16] Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]
`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update and add more clarity around this:

If you did **not** install `kubectl` via *Homebrew* but chose to do

`gcloud components install kubectl`

instead then the binary is installed inside the `bin` folder of your gcloud install folder. Even if your gcloud `bin` folder is already on your shell's `PATH` it wont see `kubectl` right away unless you start a new shell or run `hash -r` (bash / zsh) to tell your shell to discard its cached paths.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mark, I was able to sort this out, but I feel modifying the `$PATH` is a better approach. I also found that the `Caskroom` folder was in a different spot. So I recommend adding this to the relevant rc file:

```
export PATH="`brew --prefix`/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```