# Trying to run cbt (Cloud Bigtable Command Line Tool) from Google SDK

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to run the Cloud Bigtable Command Line Tool but seeing this error when I run

```
cbt help
```

or any other cbt commands:

```
-bash: cbt: command not found
```

I have verified that the gcloud component is installed when I run

```
gcloud components list
```

And I see:

```
Installed     │ Cloud Bigtable Command Line Tool                     │ cbt                      │   4.9 MiB
```

However, when I run

```
gcloud info
```

I see a list of my installed components and their version number in an array. For example:

```
Installed Components:
core: [2018.07.16]
pubsub-emulator: [2018.02.02]
beta: [2018.07.16]
gsutil: [4.33]
bq: [2.0.34]
cbt: []
bigtable: []
```

It might be a problem with the PATH not being set correctly, but I'm not sure. It seems related to this issue:

[How to set path to kubectl when installed using gcloud components install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429553/how-to-set-path-to-kubectl-when-installed-using-gcloud-components-install)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to hear you're running into this issue! Can you please provide more info in your question, such as: (a) your platform (OS + version), (b) whether you have the same issue with other binaries managed by `gcloud` such as `gsutil` or `bq`, and (c) whether your `$PATH` includes the `.../google-cloud-sdk/bin` (i.e., the installation directory of `gcloud` + `/bin`)?

Comment: (a) Platform: macOS Sierra
(b) gsutil and bq do not have the same issue. These are working as expected.

If I do `gloud info`, my installed components are:
```
Installed Components:
  core: [2018.07.16]
  pubsub-emulator: [2018.02.02]
  beta: [2018.07.16]
  gsutil: [4.33]
  bq: [2.0.34]
  cbt: []
  bigtable: []

...Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [False]
```
Not sure how to check whether $PATH includes .../google-cloud-sdk/bin

Comment: `echo $PATH` will tell you what's in your path and whether it includes the `.../google-cloud-sdk/bin` directory. Also look into that directory and see if `cbt` is installed there.

Comment: Which method you have used to install the gcloud command? Have you followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos) or used homebrew?

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things to check:

- Please provide the full output of `gcloud info`.
- Make sure that `Cloud SDK on PATH` is `True`.
- You need to have the `bin` directory of the `Installation Root` on your `PATH`.
- Make sure that the `cbt` binary is in `Installation Root/bin`

Comment: My Cloud SDK on PATH is set to False. How do I change this?

Comment: On linux/mac mac sure that your environment variable PATH includes the bin directory of the gcloud sdk. ie if you installed the sdk to your home directory then export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin.

Comment: Note, for those that may have installed gcloud with brew, your installation path may look like `/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin`. I'd suggest looking at the `gcloud info` output, specifically the `installation properties` field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have installed Google Cloud tools from Homebrew. In that case you will need to add your google-cloud-sdk bin path that will be inside homebrew path.
To find your google-cloud-sdk path you will need to do the following:

- Run "gcloud info" command.
- You will find the path printed and it could be "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/lastest/google-cloud-sdk"
- Add that path to your PATHs environment variable and don't forget to append "/bin" to that path